# DotNetNuke 7.01.01 Cannot change page names: Procedure or function 'SaveTabUrl' expects parameter '@ModifiedByUserID', which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

i have searched this on google for a while but didn't find it. When i try to change a page name in page management or on the page itself it doesn't work. This exception is thrown:

DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Procedure or function 'SaveTabUrl' 
expects parameter '@ModifiedByUserID', which was not supplied. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'SaveTabUrl' expects parameter '@ModifiedByUserID', which was not supplied. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at PetaPoco.Database.Execute(String sql, Object[] args) at DotNetNuke.Data.PetaPoco.PetaPocoHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(String connectionString, CommandType type, Int32 timeout, String sql, Object[] args) at DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider.ExecuteNonQuery(String procedureName, Object[] commandParameters) at DotNetNuke.Data.DataProvider.SaveTabUrl(Int32 tabId, Int32 seqNum, Int32 portalAliasId, Int32 portalAliasUsage, String url, String queryString, String cultureCode, String httpStatus, Boolean isSystem) at DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.Internal.TabControllerImpl.SaveTabUrl(TabUrlInfo tabUrl, Int32 portalId, Boolean clearCache) at DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController.CreateTabRedirect(TabInfo tab) at DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController.CreateTabRedirects(TabInfo tab) at DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabController.UpdateTab(TabInfo updatedTab) at DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Tabs.ManageTabs.SaveTabData(String strAction) at DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Tabs.ManageTabs.cmdUpdate_Click(Object Sender, EventArgs e) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Thank you for helping, Remco den hartog

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me this is an issue in this specific version of DNN, see the DNN issue tracker:
https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-27697?jql=text%20~%20%22SaveTabUrl%22

Upgrade to dnn712 or 7.2 will probably solve your issue.